# How to write raw MongoDB command involving regex in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In a mongo shell, I'm able to execute this command:

```
db.getSiblingDB('myDatabase')
.myCollection
.find({ 
    city_id:{$ne:123}, 
    company: {$not: new RegExp('^acme.*', 'i')}
})
.forEach(function (item) {
    var x = db.myCollection.findOne({
        city_id:123, 
        company:'abc123'
    });
    item.address = x.address;
    item.phone = x.phone;

    db.myCollection.deleteOne({_id: item._id});
    db.myCollection.insert(item);
});
```

How to write such in pymongo or any other mongodb python driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to suggestion from @AnirudhBagri, Here's what worked:

```
x = db.myCollection.find_one({city_id:123, company:'abc123'})
for item in db.myCollection.find({"$and": [{"city_id": {'$ne':123}}, {"company": {'$not': re.compile('^acme.*')}}]}):
    item.address = x.address
    item.phone = x.phone
    db.myCollection.delete_one({"_id": item._id});
    db.myCollection.insert(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pyMongo, you can do something like

```
for item in db.myDatabase.myCollection.find({ 
    city_id:{$ne:123}, 
    company: {$not: new RegExp('^acme.*', 'i')}
}):
   //Do what you are doing in ForEach fucntion
```

You can refer [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/insert/) and [remove](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/remove/) in PyMongo.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` around the `$ne:123`. Is there a way I should escape this?